# How to convert the background of the entire image to white when both white and black backgrounds are present?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

The form image contains text in different background. The image needs to be converted to one background (here white) and hence the heading needs to be converted into black.

input image :

[image]

output image:
[image]

**My approach** was to detect the grid(horizontal lines and vertical lines and sum them up) and then crop each section of the grid into new sub-images and then check the majority pixel color and transform accordingly. But after implementing that, the blue background image is not getting detected and getting cropped like :

[image]

So I am trying to **convert the entire form image into one background** so that I can avoid such outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible approach. Shades of blue will show up with a higher saturation than black and white if you convert to HSV colourspace, so...

- convert to HSV
- find mean saturation for each row and select rows where mean saturation exceeds a threshold
- greyscale those rows, invert and threshold them

This approach should work if the reverse (standout) backgrounds are any colour other than black or white. It assumes you have de-skewed your images to be truly vertical/horizontal per your example.

That could look something like this in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('form.jpg')

# Make HSV and extract S, i.e. Saturation
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
s=hsv[:,:,1]
# Save saturation just for debug
cv2.imwrite('saturation.png',s)

# Make greyscale version and inverted, thresholded greyscale version
gr = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,grinv = cv2.threshold(gr,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Find row numbers of rows with colour in them
meanSatByRow=np.mean(s,axis=1)
rows = np.where(meanSatByRow>50)

# Replace selected rows with those from the inverted, thresholded image
gr[rows]=grinv[rows]

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result.png',gr)
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The saturation image looks as follows - note that saturated colours (i.e. the blues) show up as light, everything else as black:

[image]

The greyscale, inverted image looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This approach was good... But what about **black and white** images? It would be great if you can help me with a generic approach as my input form can be anything... even black and white images.........

Comment: I'm looking at a different technique that involves `findContours()` and calculating the size and average colour of each contour to find heavily blacked boxes. I'll post a new answer if I get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different way of doing it that will cope with the *"reverse video"* being black, rather than relying on some colour saturation to find it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, greyscale and threshold
im = cv2.imread('form.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Threshold and invert
_,thr = cv2.threshold(im,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
inv   = 255 - thr

# Perform morphological closing with square 7x7 structuring element to remove details and thin lines
SE = np.ones((7,7),np.uint8)
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(thr, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, SE)
# DEBUG save closed image
cv2.imwrite('closed.png', closed)

# Find row numbers of dark rows
meanByRow=np.mean(closed,axis=1)
rows = np.where(meanByRow<50)

# Replace selected rows with those from the inverted image
im[rows]=inv[rows]

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result.png',im)
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

And the intermediate `closed` image looks like this - I artificially added a red border so you can see its extent on Stack Overflow's white background:

[image]

You can read about morphology [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) and an excellent description by Anthony Thyssen, [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/).